# How does one retrieve and model data from Firebase's Cloud Firestore using the compact map function? I tried and my code isn't working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

I was writing code for a snapshot query listener for some logs in an app I'm making. I modelled the data as a Codable protocol, but that didn't work. So I tried to manually map the key values to the data model. Here is the model:

```
// MARK: - Log Structure

struct Log : Codable {

// MARK: Properties

var date : Date

var leftUO  : Bool
var leftUI  : Bool
var leftLI  : Bool
var leftLO  : Bool

var rightUO : Bool
var rightUI : Bool
var rightLI : Bool
var rightLO : Bool
```

This is where I attempted to make a Codable Protocol.

```
enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    
    case date   = "DATE"
    
    case leftUO = "LUO"
    case leftUI = "LUI"
    case leftLI = "LLI"
    case leftLO = "LLO"
    
    case rightUO = "RUO"
    case rightUI = "RUI"
    case rightLI = "RLI"
    case rightLO = "RLO"
    
}

func dateString() -> String {
    
    let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
    dateformatter.dateStyle = .short
    let dateString = dateformatter.string(from: date)
    
    return dateString
}

func setLogImage() -> Image {
    
    // TODO - Make icons and set image based on log
    
    let image = Image("breastIcon")
    return image
}


}
```

And this is the ViewModel I used to extract the data from Firestore:

```
class Logs : ObservableObject {


// MARK: Properties
@Published var  logs =  [Log]()

// MARK: Firestore setting and retrieving Data


func createLog(uid: String, path : String,  log : Log) {
    
    let storage = Firestore.firestore()
    storage.collection(path + uid).addDocument(data: [Constants.FirebaseConstants.DATE                      : log.date,
                                                                Constants.FirebaseConstants.LEFTLOWERINNER  : log.leftLI,
                                                                Constants.FirebaseConstants.LEFTLOWEROUTER  : log.leftLO,
                                                                Constants.FirebaseConstants.LEFTUPPEROUTER  : log.leftUO,
                                                                Constants.FirebaseConstants.LEFTUPPERINNER  : log.leftUI,
                                                                Constants.FirebaseConstants.RIGHTUPPEROUTER : log.rightUO,
                                                                Constants.FirebaseConstants.RIGHTUPPERINNER : log.rightUI,
                                                                Constants.FirebaseConstants.RIGHTLOWERINNER : log.rightLI,
                                                                Constants.FirebaseConstants.RIGHTLOWEROUTER : log.rightLO
    ])
    
    
}
```

This is the specific method of the ViewModel where I add the querySnapshotListner.

```
func retrieveLogs(uid: String) {
    


    let storage = Firestore.firestore()
    
    storage.collection(Constants.FirebaseConstants.LOGSCOLLECTIONS + uid).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unable to retrieve documents.")
            return
        }
        
        self.logs = documents.compactMap({ (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Log? in
            
            let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            
            let date    = data[Constants.FirebaseConstants.DATE]            as? Date ?? Date()
            let leftUO  = data[Constants.FirebaseConstants.LEFTUPPEROUTER]  as? Bool ?? false
            let leftUI  = data[Constants.FirebaseConstants.LEFTUPPERINNER]  as? Bool ?? false
            let leftLI  = data[Constants.FirebaseConstants.LEFTLOWERINNER]  as? Bool ?? false
            let leftLO  = data[Constants.FirebaseConstants.LEFTLOWEROUTER]  as? Bool ?? false
            
            let rightUO  = data[Constants.FirebaseConstants.RIGHTUPPEROUTER] as? Bool ?? false
            let rightUI  = data[Constants.FirebaseConstants.RIGHTUPPERINNER] as? Bool ?? false
            let rightLI  = data[Constants.FirebaseConstants.RIGHTLOWERINNER] as? Bool ?? false
            let rightLO  = data[Constants.FirebaseConstants.RIGHTLOWEROUTER] as? Bool ?? false
            
            return Log(date: date, leftUO: leftUO, leftUI: leftUI, leftLI: leftLI, leftLO: leftLO, rightUO: rightUO, rightUI: rightUI, rightLI: rightLI, rightLO: rightLO)
            
            
        })
        
    }
    print(self.logs.count)
    

}


}
```

I call the  retrieveLogs(:_) method of the Logs structure in the UserInfo ViewModel like so:

```
class UserInfo : ObservableObject {


//MARK: - Properties

@Published var user                : FBUser      = .init(uid: "", name : "", email : "")
@Published var isUserAuthenticated : FBAuthState = .undefined
@Published var userLogs            : [Log]       = []


//MARK: -  FirebaseIDToken Listener Method

func configureFirebaseStateDidChange() {
    
    _ = Auth.auth().addIDTokenDidChangeListener { [self] (_ , user) in
        
        guard user != nil else {
            
            self.isUserAuthenticated = .signedOut
            return
        }
        
        self.isUserAuthenticated = .signedIn
        
        self.user.email          = user?.email          ?? ""
        self.user.name           = user?.displayName    ?? ""
        self.user.uid            = user?.uid            ?? ""
        
        

    }
    
    guard user.uid != "" else {
        
        // UID is not retrieved
        return
    }
    
    retrieveUserLogs()
}



func retrieveUserLogs() {
    
    let logs = Logs()
    
    logs.retrieveLogs(uid: user.uid)
}



}
```

When the prints on the console, it says it has a value of 0. I tried to edit my code in a variety of ways with no avail. Thanks in advance for the help, Id really appreciate it!!

EDIT: The error I keep getting is that the logs keep returning with a value of 0, whereas I was expecting an array of Logs. And here's a screenshot of my Cloud Firestore database:

[/LOGS/USERS/UID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7RPR.png)

[/USERS/UID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iotfM.png)

Comment: What was the issue with Codable? I strongly encourage folks to use Codable whenever possible, as it will make your life so much easier. Check out the code snippet in the docs - it shows how to securely and safely map data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects

Comment: Please indicate the error that you are seeing.

Comment: The error I keep getting is that the logs keep returning with a value of 0, whereas I was expecting an array of Logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Firebase calls are asynchronous (an easy way to tell a call is asynchronous is the fact it has a completion block / callback).

In your example, you set up a snapshot listener which will be called asynchronously.

The print statement is outside of the snapshot listener, so it will be executed *immediately* after you've set up the listener. This is before the snapshot listener has received any data, so the result will always be zero.

Move the print statement inside the snapshot listener, like this:

```
storage.collection(...).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
  // ... code to map documents goes here

  self.logs = documents.compactMap(...)

  // at this time, self.logs will contain the collection of mapped documents (1)
  print(self.logs.count)
}
```

Note (1) - assuming the collection was non-empty, and mapping the documents was possible (i.e. using all the correct field names).

Again, I strongly recommend using Firebase's Codable support. If you post a screenshot of how the data model looks like in the Firestore data browser, I can take a stab at sketching the mapping code for you.

Comment: I edited my question to include the database, and I would love for you to have a jab at it and let me know how I'm messing up my code, since I'm a pretty junior developer I am really eager to learn!! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you also include a screenshot that shows how the documents in the users collection look like? I need to see the attributes.

Comment: I've added the screenshot of the users collection, please let me know how I could configure this to a codable protocol